# The this keyword in Dart, string interpolation

Tags: dart

The Dart Editor doesn't seem to recognize `$this.keyword`, where `keyword` is a field of a class. The expression is located in a function of a method context. But it does recognize `$keyword`. The confusion is, why doesn't it recognize `$this.keyword`, the `this` keyword should be rigid like in C# or Java.

```dart
class TryMe {
 String keyword;

 void hi(Function callback) {
  callback(() => return '$this.keyword');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the interpolation part is not an identifier but an expression you need to add `{}`

```dart
callback(() => return '${this.keyword}');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code is doing, but you don't usually use `this` to refer to class fields. You can rewrite your code as:

```
class TryMe {
  String keyword;

  void hi(Function callback) {
    callback(() => keyword);
  }
}
```

Also note that you don't need a `return` when using `=>` syntax.

Comment: You're right about that. Is there an article about whether you can omit the `this` keyword? What mechanism is it driven by?

Comment: If you write a variable name, like `x`, and there is no declaration of `x` in the textual scope, then it always means `this.x`. If there is a declaration in scope, and it is an instance member, then it also means `this.x`. Otherwise it refers to the static/top-level/local variable declaration instead.